# i need to find a faster way to load/show all my assets on Polakdot testnet Westend

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, kusama, westend, test-network

I use Polakdot.js library to show all of my assets on the Westend testnet in my dapp.

It takes around 5 seconds to load/show all my assets.

For now it seems to me that this library doesn't have the function to show all assets on wallet address immediately.

How i fetch all my assets from Westend:

- fetch all assets on Westend
- check for each asset if my balance is bigger than 0
- show list of all assets where i have balance more than 0

The problem here is that i loop every time over all the assets on the chain and check for each of them if i have any balance and that is slow.

is there a way to check all the assets i have in my wallet without having to loop over all the assets on the chain ?

app -> https://app.dotacp.mvpworkshop.co/swap?network=westend

Answer (score 0):

This is a common bottleneck when interacting with wallets in general, most wallets don't have a built-in index of all assets you hold. You can see if [Subscan API](https://support.subscan.io/) meets your needs or you'll just need to cache it locally and have a background worker to periodically refresh the data.